Is it possible to know where the Sun is just by looking at the Moon?
A nine year old child asked me if it is possible to know where the Sun is located just by looking at the Moon from the Earth.
I said I don't know, that I only know that the lunar surface reflects the Sun's light in a mirror-like way.
But I am curious, is it possible?

Related: Why does the light side of the moon appear not to line up correctly with the evening sun?

I would say that the lunar surface reflects the Sun's light in more of a dirty gray painted wall-like way.

@Solomon Well, yes. The Moon's albedo is similar to that of aged asphalt, and it doesn't reflect like a mirror, it's a Lambertian reflector.

Intuitively, if I shine a lamp on a tennis ball, you should have a good idea of where the lamp is just by looking at the ball.

@SolomonSlow It's not gray though, more like brown, since the albedo at 800 nm is about twice that at 400 nm and changes approximately linearly in between.

@Viktor K "where the Sun is" --> do you want to know the direction of the sun (where it is in the sky) or its solar system position (direction and distance)?  (I suspect the first.)  Some distance info is possible but crude given the slightly non-circular and 3D aspects of the bodies.

Yes it is possible.
First, take a look at the moon. First, the light side of the moon
tells you generally which direction the sun is. But now you need to estimate exactly how far across the sky the sun is. To do that, first estimate how far across the moon the dark side is. Let's call this fraction $f$. Then the angle $\theta$ in the diagram below is given by $1-2f=\cos(180-\theta)$, or $\theta=-\cos^{-1}(2f-1)$. Since this is for a child, just know the general rule that if the moon is full, the sun is $180$ degrees away, if the moon is half, the sun is $90$ degrees away, and if the moon is "new," well then you can probably see the sun because it's right behind the moon. If the moon is somewhere between those cases, the sun is somewhere between those results.
So once you have $\theta$ you know which direction the sun is in and how far it is in that direction. Try to make that angle with your arms, with one arm pointing toward the moon, and the other arm making the angle $\theta$ generally toward the light side, and you know where the sun is.


Re: "and if the moon is "new," well then you can probably see the sun because it's right behind the moon" -- if by "behind" you mean in the same line of sight then that happens only in a solar eclipse. Most of the time, in a new moon it's only that the sun is in the same direction but the three bodies are not exactly aligned. In fact it means there must be a very small "sliver" of illumination of the lunar surface visible even on a new moon, but it is probably impossible to discern with the human eye.

Is there any way we can calculate distance? I'm guessing in theory we know how long a lunar month is and the rotation speed of the earth, which could give us information as $f$ varies over time. But ignoring all that, is there a way we could calculate distance just from the light of the moon?

@Amit who said we're limited to the human eye?

"how far across the sun the dark side is." - did you mean "across the moon"?

@JEB no one. I mentioned it to explain why we don't notice it

I've tried to explain this to people, without drawing pictures, when both the sun and the moon were in the sky at the same time. I pointed out that the sun was shining on us, and you can look at the moon and see how it is lit by the sun. On the part of the moon that was lit up, it was daytime on the moon; on the dark part of the moon, it was night. Some people simply could not understand it. Unrelated anecdote: A friend called me last April and asked, "What did you think of that eclipse the other night?" (We live in the path of totality.) I said, "Yes, an eclipse always looks better at night."

@JEB Any earthly electronic camera will also have a hard time imaging this sliver of illumination due to the solar aureole, which is much brighter.

Yes, you can predict the sun's position in the sky from the moon's phase.
Some examples:
At half moon the sun is located $90°$ away from the moon.


At full moon the sun is located opposite (i.e. $180°$ away) from the moon.
This also means the sun is below the horizon when the moon is above the horizon.

At new moon the sun is located very close (i.e. nearly $0°$ away) from the moon.
This means the sun is nearly behind the moon.

I think there are corrections required for finite distances (you need to know them)...because iirc, the distance to the sun was once measured by getting the moon's orbital phase when it was exactly visually a 1/2 moon..it's greater the $|\pm 90|$.

@JEB I know there are small corrections to this (see On the sizes and distances). But to keep the explanation simple I chose to ignore this, thus treating the sun as infinitely far away.

I know you know,  just pointing it out...and I recently watched a video on the cosmic distance ladder, starting with the size of the Earth and shadow-at-noon thing from antiquity. Lunar eclipses and phases were next, and transits of Venus.
